# Finding out the type of a triangle in Bash

Tags: bash

I have this block of code to determine whether a triangle is **Isosceles, Scalene or Equilateral** after reading three inputs, **X** , **Y** and **Z**.
Its constraints are:

1. It should be between 1 and 1000
2. The sum of any two sides should be greater than the third

It works well except for specific numbers such as 5 and 6 in which it doesn't output anything.

```
read X
read Y
read Z

if [[ $X -lt 1000 && $Y -lt 1000 && $Z -lt 1000 ]]
then 
    if [[ $X -gt 1 && $Y -gt 1 && $Z -gt 1 ]]
    then
        if [[ $((X + Y)) > $Z  &&  $((X + Z)) > $Y  &&  $((Y + Z)) > $X ]]
        then
            if [[ $X == $Y  &&  $X == $Z && $Y == $Z ]]
            then
                echo EQUILATERAL
            elif [[ $X == $Y && $X == $Z ]] || [[ $Y == $Z || $Y == $X ]] || [[ $Z == $Y || $Z == $X ]]
            then 
                echo ISOSCELES
            else
                echo SCALENE
            fi
        fi
    fi

fi
```

Please explain why it's not working as expected

Comment: `>` is for string matches. Use `-gt` for numbers. inside `[[`..`]]`, `==` is for pattern matches. Use `-eq` for numbers.

Comment: Consider quoting refernces to X, Y, Z not inside arithmetic expressions e.g. '`if $X -lt 10000`. It will protect against bad input.

Comment: @small_potato : Why don't you put every condition into arithmetic parentheses, i.e. `if (( (X+Y) > Z && (Y+Z) > Y && (Y+Z) > X ));then`. Doing it this way, it is more readable and you can use `>` for numeric comparision.

Comment: @jhnc I see the error I had made and corrected it

Comment: @user1934428 thank you for the tip. It does make code easier to read

Answer (score 1):

As @jhnc comments, `>` within `[[ .. ]]` operator is for string comparison.
If you input 5's for x, y, and z, the comparison test will look like:

```
if [[ 10 > 5 ]] ...
```

which returns `false` as a result of string comparison.
Please use `arithmetic evaluation` `(( .. ))` instead.

Then how about:

```
read x
read y
read z

# As a first step, eliminate error cases to simplify the logic
if (( x >= 1000 || y >= 1000 || z >= 1000 || x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0)); then
    echo "out of range"
    exit
fi

if (( x + y <= z || y + z <= x || z + x <= y )); then
    echo "not a triangle"
    exit
fi

if (( x == y && y == z )); then
    echo "equilateral"
elif (( x == y || y == z || z == x )); then
    echo "isosceles"
else
    echo "scalene"
fi
```